# A better way of creating from a class parameter?

Tags: delphi

In `TApplication.CreateForm` (not sure if it is allowed to paste the code here. I will do so if somemone confirms) it seems a way of creating an instance of a TForm descendant by using the class of the derived form and a variable pointing to the form. Both are parameters of `CreateForm`;

```
procedure TApplication.CreateForm(InstanceClass: TComponentClass; var Reference);
```

Is there a better or even simpler way (maybe with less code) of doing what is done in `CreateForm` if I wanted to have a method which creates a derived control with only some parameters as indicators of what class it is and the variable it will be using.

EDIT: I would like to have a method that creates a control which I use in my project. The method will also do some additional code related to the control so that is the reason for the method. I do not want to duplicate that additional work and the method will be called numerous times. I can implement the code in the same way as `CreateForm` but was wondering if there is a way of doing the same in less or simpler code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Less code or alternative code which you would consider as better code.

Comment: What about less code?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand what you mean but I am asking if there is possibly less code or simpler code than what is used inside CreateForm.

Comment: No, your edit helped tremendously. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to have a method which creates a derived control with only some parameters as indicators of what class it is and the variable it will be using.

You don't need a method for that. You can write it like this:

```
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(Owner);
```

Don't be put off by all the code in `Application.CreateForm`. That code performs many tasks, the principle of which is to assign the `Application.MainForm` variable. The IDE likes to encourage you to use `Application.CreateForm` but in reality you only need to call it once, and that is to create the main form.

If you are dead set on making this into a method then it would look like this:

```
function CreateForm(FormClass: TFormClass; Owner: TComponent): TForm;
begin
  Result := FormClass.Create(Owner);
end;
```

When calling this function you would need to cast the value returned:

```
MyForm := TMyForm(CreateForm(TMyForm, Owner));
```

or

```
MyForm := CreateForm(TMyForm, Owner) as TMyForm;
```

As an alternative you could use a generic method:

```
type
  TFormCreator = class
  public
    class function CreateForm<T: TForm>(Owner: TComponent): T; static;
  end;
```

Implement it like this:

```
class function TFormCreator.CreateForm<T>(Owner: TComponent): T;
begin
  Result := T(TFormClass(T).Create(Owner));
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
MyForm := TFormCreator.CreateForm<TMyForm>(Owner);
```

Pretty ridiculous isn't it? All you want to do is instantiate a form! So, I have a strong suspicion that you have been confused by the IDE's use of `Application.CreateForm` and believe that there is more to instantiating forms than there really is. My instincts tell me that you are actually looking for this:

```
MyForm := TMyForm.Create(Owner);
```

Comment: CreateForm is also called for each Auto-Created form of course

Comment: I covered that: *The IDE likes to encourage you to use Application.CreateForm but in reality you only need to call it once, and that is to create the main form.* The fact that the IDE does that does not imply that you need to do it. As I explained, you should call `Application.CreateForm` exactly once, when you create your main form.

Comment: Excellent! Your edit explains exactly how it could be done. Thanks a mil. Less code and simpler.

Answer (score -1):

AS. You can post YOUR OWN code, but with regards to code which copyrights holds someone else - that gets a bit complicated. I believe it falls under USA "Fair Use" doctrine. For example you can post a snippet of VCL source to criticize or demonstrate something, but not to copy-paste it into another project and only as little of the VCL code - as required for that "fair use" intention.

A VCL form is a component, thus it needs an owner, who would be responsible for memory management. So you can create the form in a typical `TComponent` creation pattern.

```
  MyFormVariable := TMyFormClass.Create( Application );
```

This also adds for type safety that untyped `var Reference` in `CreateForm` denies.

Whether that way is better or worse than using `Application.CreateForm` is up to your tastes. Personally I prefer uniform way so when I need to create a form or a datamodule explicitly I usually go the "component" way not the "application" way.

I guess (just guess) that back in old days `TApplication.CreateForm` added some extra required setup that "component way" of creating forms could not do, at least not before VCL would get started by `Application.Run` call. Or maybe there were types of `TApplication` - and AFAIR there are 5 ones for different projects - that were not derived from `TComponent`? But anyway I think today that limitations - if ever there where any - not apply any more.

Comment: The only reason to use `Application.CreateForm` is to create your main form. That is the only way to create a main form. A VCL application should have a single call to `Application.CreateForm`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The IDE doesn't know that. It creates every auto-create form that way. ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The IDE knows this. The first one is the main form. The rest are not.

Comment: But it uses CreateForm for all forms, not just for the first one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you can disable form/data-modules auto creation: Uncheck Tools>Options>VCL Designer>Auto create forms and data modules

Comment: @AgustinOrtu: Nice to know, but not what I was hinting at.